# Updating a column matching a specific pattern in all table in an oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I need to update a column matching a specific pattern in all tables in an oracle database.
For example I have in all tables this column *_CID with is a foreign key to master table witch has a primary key CID

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the naming convention and query `all_tab_columns`

```
declare
    cursor c is 
        select table_owner , column_name, table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name like '%_CID';
begin 
    for x in c loop
        execute immediate 'update ' || x.table_owner || '.' || x.table_name ||' set ' || x.column_name||' = 0';
    end loop;
end;
```

If you have valid Fk's you can also use `all_tab_constraints` the fetch enabled FK's for your main table and fetch the columns name of the `r_constraint_name`.

Comment: The problem is I don't know if I have a valid FK's or not

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question:

```
BEGIN  
  FOR x IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns) LOOP   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'update ' || x.owner || '.' || x.table_name ||' set ' || x.column_name||' = 0 where '||x.column_name||' = 1';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

thanks